# Merging two files depending on column in shell script

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files

A.txt:

```
539159564|43009076L|NNN|01/01/1979
1614536048|37334120Z|NNN|01/01/1979
1881826961|09406066D|NNN|01/01/1979
```

B.txt:

```
610505542|610505542
539159564|607811916
659839155|659839155
1614536048|663068075
1881826961|659839155
653820753|653820753
653960579|653960579
```

Now need to make C.txt with below data

C.txt:

```
539159564|43009076L|NNN|01/01/1979|607811916
1614536048|37334120Z|NNN|01/01/1979|663068075
1881826961|09406066D|NNN|01/01/1979|659839155
```

I have been trying awk but was not getting proper result.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{b[$1]=$2;next}$1 in b{print $0 FS b[$1]}' B.txt A.txt
```